# Detecting whether the calling function is static or not

Tags: c++, boost, c++-loki

I am trying to control the access to non-const member functions from a singleton. I maintain a typelist of all classes which have are allowed to access the non-const member functions of a singleton. I am planning to use BOOST_TYPEOF(this) to detect at compile time if the class is present in the typelist. However, this check is invalid from a static member function or a non-class functions. Is there a way to detect this at compile-time.

```
class A;
class B;
class C;

class Singleton{
    ....
    public:
       typedef LOKI_TYPELIST_2(ClassA, classB) allowed_list;
       void doF_modify();
       void doF() const;
}
#define set_pointer_check(A, TypeOfA) if(Loki::TL::IndexOf<Singleton::allowed_list, \
                                BOOST_TYPEOF(this)>::value == -1)\ //No non-const
                                 std::static_assert(Loki::IsSame<BOOST_TYPEOF(A), \
                                              const\
                                              TypeOfA*>::value);

void A::doF() {
   A* ptr;
   set_pointer_chec(ptr, A);
}
void B::doF() {
   B* ptr;
   set_pointer_chec(ptr, B);
}
void C::doF() {
   C* ptr;
   set_pointer_chec(ptr, C);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you make them friend classes and make the non-const member functions private.

Comment: because friendship is not inherited. I will also check if TypeOfA is derived from any of the classes in the typelist, allowed_list.

Comment: How do you initialize the pointer `ptr`? Anyway, if I understand you correctly, your problem is restricting access to some of the singletons members only to specific classes and all their subclasses, right?

Comment: Make a base class that is a friend of the singleton and contains protected member functions to call the singleton functions. Inherit from this class and call the protected functions.